# Kafka with spark structuredstreaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

We are doing Kafka with Spark structured streaming while executing we are getting the issue below:

```
    Ivy Default Cache set to: /root/.ivy2/cache
 The jars for the packages stored in: /root/.ivy2/jars
 :: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark2/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
 org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11 added as a dependency
 org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients added as a dependency
 :: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.2.0 in central
    found org.apache.spark#spark-tags_2.11;2.2.0 in local-m2-cache
    found org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 in local-m2-cache
    found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;0.10.1.0 in local-m2-cache
    found net.jpountz.lz4#lz4;1.3.0 in local-m2-cache
    found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.2.6 in local-m2-cache
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.21 in local-m2-cache
 :: resolution report :: resolve 3640ms :: artifacts dl 20ms
    :: modules in use:
    net.jpountz.lz4#lz4;1.3.0 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;0.10.1.0 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.2.0 from central in [default]
    org.apache.spark#spark-tags_2.11;2.2.0 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.21 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.2.6 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    :: evicted modules:
    org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;0.10.0.1 by [org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;0.10.1.0] in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   8   |   2   |   2   |   1   ||   7   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 :: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 7 already retrieved (0kB/30ms)
 18/03/14 15:52:02 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235
 18/03/14 15:52:02 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: StructuredKafkaWordCount
...
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark2/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235.jar at spark://172.16.10.53:31702/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235.jar with timestamp 1521022925004
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark2/examples/jars/scopt_2.11-3.3.0.jar at spark://172.16.10.53:31702/jars/scopt_2.11-3.3.0.jar with timestamp 1521022925006
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark2/examples/jars/spark-assembly_2.10-0.9.0-incubating.jar at spark://172.16.10.53:31702/jars/spark-assembly_2.10-0.9.0-incubating.jar with timestamp 1521022925006
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.spark_spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar at spark://172.16.10.53:31702/jars/org.apache.spark_spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar with timestamp 1521022925006
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-0.10.1.0.jar at spark://172.16.10.53:31702/jars/org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-0.10.1.0.jar with timestamp 1521022925006
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.spark_spark-tags_2.11-2.2.0.jar at spark://172.16.10.53:31702/jars/org.apache.spark_spark-tags_2.11-2.2.0.jar with timestamp 1521022925006
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/.ivy2/jars/org.spark-project.spark_unused-1.0.0.jar at spark://172.16.10.53:31702/jars/org.spark-project.spark_unused-1.0.0.jar with timestamp 1521022925007
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/.ivy2/jars/net.jpountz.lz4_lz4-1.3.0.jar at spark://172.16.10.53:31702/jars/net.jpountz.lz4_lz4-1.3.0.jar with timestamp 1521022925007
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/.ivy2/jars/org.xerial.snappy_snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar at spark://172.16.10.53:31702/jars/org.xerial.snappy_snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar with timestamp 1521022925007
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/.ivy2/jars/org.slf4j_slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar at spark://172.16.10.53:31702/jars/org.slf4j_slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar with timestamp 1521022925007
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 11138.
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 172.16.10.53:11138
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.10.53, 11138, None)
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 172.16.10.53:11138 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.10.53, 11138, None)
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.10.53, 11138, None)
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.10.53, 11138, None)
 18/03/14 15:52:05 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@10bea4{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
 18/03/14 15:52:07 INFO EventLoggingListener: Logging events to hdfs:///spark2-history/local-1521022925116
 18/03/14 15:52:07 INFO SharedState: loading hive config file: file:/etc/spark2/2.6.3.0-235/0/hive-site.xml
 18/03/14 15:52:07 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark2/bin/spark-warehouse/').
 18/03/14 15:52:07 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark2/bin/spark-warehouse/'.
 18/03/14 15:52:07 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@e700eba{/SQL,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
 18/03/14 15:52:07 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7186b202{/SQL/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
 18/03/14 15:52:07 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3d88e6b9{/SQL/execution,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
 18/03/14 15:52:07 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@208205ed{/SQL/execution/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
 18/03/14 15:52:07 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2173a742{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
 18/03/14 15:52:09 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
 18/03/14 15:52:13 INFO StreamExecution: Starting [id = 7880cf41-0bbc-4b40-a284-c41f9dcbfbc8, runId = 5636831e-aad8-43e4-8d99-9a4b27b69b9f]. Use /tmp/temporary-a86e0bc9-99fd-45dd-b38a-4c5fc10def22 to store the query checkpoint.
 18/03/14 15:52:13 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = 7880cf41-0bbc-4b40-a284-c41f9dcbfbc8, runId = 5636831e-aad8-43e4-8d99-9a4b27b69b9f] terminated with error
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArrayDeserializer
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createSource(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:155)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(StreamExecution.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan(StreamExecution.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 47 more
 Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = 7880cf41-0bbc-4b40-a284-c41f9dcbfbc8, runId = 5636831e-aad8-43e4-8d99-9a4b27b69b9f]" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArrayDeserializer
 === Streaming Query ===
 Identifier: [id = 7880cf41-0bbc-4b40-a284-c41f9dcbfbc8, runId = 5636831e-aad8-43e4-8d99-9a4b27b69b9f]
 Current Committed Offsets: {}
 Current Available Offsets: {}

 Current State: INITIALIZING
 Thread State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArrayDeserializer
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createSource(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:155)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(StreamExecution.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan(StreamExecution.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:276)
    ... 1 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 47 more
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArrayDeserializer
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createSource(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:155)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(StreamExecution.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan(StreamExecution.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 47 more
 18/03/14 15:52:13 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
 18/03/14 15:52:13 INFO AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@30221a6b{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4041}
 18/03/14 15:52:13 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.16.10.53:4041
 18/03/14 15:52:14 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
 18/03/14 15:52:14 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
 18/03/14 15:52:14 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
 18/03/14 15:52:14 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
 18/03/14 15:52:14 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
 18/03/14 15:52:14 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
 18/03/14 15:52:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
 18/03/14 15:52:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-bfc1f921-8877-4dc8-81ed-dfcba6da84c0
 18/03/14 15:52:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/temporary-a86e0bc9-99fd-45dd-b38a-4c5fc10def22
```

Before this, we imported spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.0.2.jar using spark shell.
 We even tried to run the example in hortonworks using the `./runexample` command.

Versions:

- Kafka = 0.10.1
- Spark = 2.2.0

Answer (score 3):

It needs two jars 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0'
and 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.1.0', import both of them.

Instead of specifying jars manually you can use,

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.1.0
```

It will automatically download jars with it.

Answer (score 2):

Spark provides spark-streaming-kafka-0.8 package with its release version, and when you try to add spark-sql-kafka-0.10 structured streaming package, the kafka client conflicts with the one in the streaming package.

**And that's the reason if you follow the other answers under this question, and you find that doesn't work at all.**

That's why you included the spark-sql-kafka-0.10 package in your pom, or with '--jars', or with 'driver.extraClasspath' , and you still get a ClassNotFound exception.

The only thing you have to do is :

1. delete the jar file in your path: `${SPARK_HOME}/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11.jar`
2. use `--jars ${your_lib}/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11.jar,${your_lib}/kafka-clients-${your_version}.jar` with your `spark-submit` command.
3. besides, you may have to delete the lib file `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11.jar` on HDFS , if you have `spark.yarn.jars` , and you have put your spark lib in that directory.

Comment: @Can If you have added the `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` jar and still got `ClassNotFound` / `NoSuchMethod` , this is most likely to work. Anyway, you should know whether your exception is caused by class conflict.

Answer (score 1):

@Souvik is correct but what ever he specified is not a kafka-clients jar (but that is required too). Following is a sample spark-submit statement.

```
spark-submit --jars spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0.jar,kafka-clients-0.10.2.2.jar your-file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're missing the kafka-clients jar. Pass this **spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.0.2.jar** during spark-submit

```
spark-submit --jars /yourpath/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.0.2.jar
```